# Passing Functions to Reactives in R-Shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, shiny-server

### Issue:

I'm interested in displaying three graphs in a shiny web app. I have written three functions to graph each type of plot for a specified range. The function's parameter takes a input parameter, region, and subsets the larger data.frame for that specified region and subsequently graphs it.

I'm having difficulty passing this function into an r-shiny reactive element.

### Here is my function:

```
plot_30cumulative <- function(enter_region) { 

  subset <<- HPF[HPF$region == enter_region, ]

  thirty_year_cumulative <<- ggplot(subset, aes(x=subset$date)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = subset$BaseCumulative, color = "Base"), color = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(y = subset$StressCumulative, color = "Adjusted"), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_x_date(name = "",
                 date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d",
                 limits = as.Date(c("2014-02-15", "2044-02-15")), 
                 breaks = seq(as.Date("2014-02-15"), as.Date("2044-02-15"), by = "1 year")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Cumulative Growth Rates",
                       breaks = seq(min(subset$StressCumulative),max(subset$BaseCumulative), .25),
                       limits = c(NA, 4),                                                                   # Temporarily hard-coded for better visability.
                       labels = percent) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    ggtitle("Cumulative 30-Year Growth Rates")
```

### What I Want in Shiny:

```
library(shiny)

#Define UI for dataset
ui <- fluidPage(

  #App title ----
  titlePanel("Home Price Forecasting under Stress Scenarios"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      #Input: Stress Path Function Parameters ----

      #Input: Numeric entry for region to plot ----
      numericInput(inputId = "region",
                   label = "Enter Region Number:",
                   value = "1", 
                   min = 1, 
                   max = 110)

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "ThYrC"),
              plotOutput(outputId = "FiYrC"), 
              plotOutput(outputId = "FoYrQtr")
    )

  )
)


#Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output){


       output$ThYrC <- renderPlot({reactive(plot_30cumulative(enter_region == input$region)}))

  }                   

# Run the application ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Problem:

I can't seem to pass the function parameter, `enter_region`, to the reactive element by `input$region == enter_region`.

Any insight into this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Try `output$ThYrC <- renderPlot(region_5cumulative(enter_region == input$region))` - that is eliminate the unneeded reactive in the `renderPlot.` 2) The function name is  `plot_30cumulative ` up top but `region_5cumulative` in the app - is that a cut and paste error ? 3) What error or behavior do you see?

Comment: @JohnPaul If I want the graph to change when the region input changes, wouldn't I need this reactive to update the plot?

Comment: `renderPlot` is automatically reactive, so you don't need to add the extra `reactive` statement.